# Solaris library linking with STLport4.6.2 giving ostream related undefined error

Tags: c++, stl, operators, undefined, ostream

I have a legacy C++ project and now I am compiling it with stlport4 first time.

what I did is: 
1. built a libmcommon_stl library: compiled with -libraty=stlport4 -library=no%Csd. I didn't disable ostream in STL config and all ok till here;

2. started full project compilation along with above library, got linker error
   LINKING ERROR:
   rtlink -cxx -optimized -i -mt -L/home/my/SunCC/prod/lib  -L/home/my/misc/sqlite3/lib -lsqlite3 -L//home/my/misc_libs/solaris-32bit-tools/xerces-c-3/lib -lxerces-c -library=stlport4   -o ../../bin/testcpp_stl obj_rel/testcpp_stl.o -lposix4 -L/home/my/lib -L/home/my/misc/STLport4.6.2/lib -lstlport_sunpro -Bdynamic -L/home/my/misc/sourcepro5_stlport462/lib -loas -L. -R/home/my/misc/sqlite3/lib  -ltls7712d -lmcommon_stl -ldbt5312d  -L../lib -L/home/my/misc/ACE5.3_STLport4.6.2/ACE_wrappers/ace -lACE -lNOTIF

Undefined                       first referenced
 symbol                             in file
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &,const RWCollectableString&) /home/my/lib/libmcommon_stl.so

I understood that linker is not able to find operator<< definition and verified the code like related to this :

cerr << *(RWCollectableString*)rwhIterator.value() << endl;

I tried with -library=Cstd but seen lots of errors. How to link with ostream? Now can get rid of cerr dependency?

Answer (score 0):

`<iostream>` and the STL are historically unrelated. Since 1998, the two became related when both became part of the Standard Library = `namespace std`. At that point, the two were glued together.

STLport is a continuation of the pre-1998 STL. Glueing it to IOstreams is a bit tricky, because what exact stream is expected? STLport's main use is in platforms which miss a Standard Library altogether, so there's a replacement for the standard IOstreams, but also an option to use the Standard IOstreams.

From your errors, it appears you're inconsistent in your choice of streams. Which one did you want?